# Sikuli script randomly crashes via java crash or unable to find image

Tags: python, jython, sikuli

I have a script that I run 24/7 and it will randomly crash. Sometimes not for 3 days and sometimes less than 4 hours. I currently use an automouse clicker to restart any soft crashes (unable to find x), but what can I do for the bigger ones that crash java entirely and stop the program from operating at all?

Comment: have you submitted the bug to the sikuli devs?